# Express JS issue functions not loading

Tags: firebase, express, async-await

I want to load my functions into firebase but i keep getting an error after trying to deploy running `firebase deploy` but I get `Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'async'`. I suspect it is line 65 - 70 that is giving me an issue but can figure out why.   [Link to image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmzTc.png)

Comment: This would probably be the line `var async = require('async')`. Do you use the async module (it isn't needed for what you're showing)? If you do, try running `npm install async`.

Comment: @nthnchu that worked! however now im getting ReferenceError: req is not defined

Comment: I've fixed that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors here. The error you are getting is caused by this part:

```js
var async = require('async')
```

The error means that you don't have the `async` package installed. You can install it by running `npm install async`. You don't need the `async` package for asynchronous functions like the ones you are using.

---

The other error is in the following code:

```js
app.delete("/:id", async (req, res => {
     admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(req.params.id).delete();
    res.status(200).send()
}))
```

It should be:

```js
app.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
     admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(req.params.id).delete();
    res.status(200).send()
})
```